# How does a computer write more data than the command data size

Tags: binary, command, arguments

So in my attempts to build a computer on a program called logisim i have run into a major problem. If a command code takes up 1-byte and then arguments such as where to store data take up another byte, then how does a computer write more than the command size.

For example.

Command code 0001 means set currently selected memory slot, then the second half 0110 is the data to set. But that would mean that you can only set half the data you started with. I hope this is concise enough.

Answer (score 0):

Computer programs can set/write more data than their instruction set because of "Jump" instructions. These instructions move the instruction pointer to a different position. This allows previous instructions to be repeated. This repetition allows the computer to set/write infinite amounts of data.